# Programatically created NSTableView column widths do not line up with header

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have a programatically created NSTableView that I am adding new columns to:

```
func createColumnsOnTable(table : NSTableView, columnNames: String[], hideColumns: String[])
{
    for columnNum in 0 .. 2
    {
        let columnName = columnNames[columnNum]
        var newTableColumn = NSTableColumn()
        var newHeaderCell = NSTableHeaderCell()
        newTableColumn.setHeaderCell(newHeaderCell)
        newTableColumn.setIdentifier(columnName.lowercaseString)

        newHeaderCell.setTitle(columnName)
        newTableColumn.setEditable(true)
        newTableColumn.sizeToFit()
        newTableColumn.setResizingMask(NSTableColumnUserResizingMask)
        //newHeaderCell.drawSortIndicatorWithFrame(table.headerView().frame(), inView: table.headerView(), ascending: true, priority: 0)

        if isInSet(columnName, valueArray: hideColumns)
        {
            newTableColumn.setHidden(true)
        }
        var sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: newTableColumn.identifier(), ascending: true, selector: "compare")
        newTableColumn.setSortDescriptorPrototype(sortDescriptor)
        table.addTableColumn(newTableColumn)
    }
}
```

My problem is the new columns display fine and look OK but the vertical gridline is not lined up with the divider in the header.  In addition as the divider is dragged to make the column wider the column gets wider but the alignment gets even more skewed. I'm not sure how to get them to stay lined up when resizing the column or how to even get them to start off lined up.  When I use a tableview created in IB I don't have this problem so I know I'm missing something but just can't find what.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the reason.  When trying to work out why I had no scroll bars I had added a setBoundsSize setting on the contentView of the scrollView containing the tableView.  Once I got rid of that line all started behaving as normal.  Just in case anyone else runs into this issue (however unlikely that may be) the line I removed was:

```
newScrollView.contentView().setBoundsSize(newScrollView.bounds().size)
```